# Custom row (List of CustomTypes) to spark dataframe

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am currently having some problems with creating a Spark Row object and converting it to a spark dataframe. What i am trying to achieve is,

I have a two lists of custom types that look more or less like the classes below,

```scala
case class MyObject(name:String,age:Int)
case class MyObject2(xyz:String,abc:Double)

val listOne = List(MyObject("aaa",22),MyObject("sss",223)),
val listTwo = List(MyObject2("bbb",23),MyObject2("abc",2332))
```

Using these two lists I want to create a Dataframe which has one row and two fields (fieldOne and fieldTwo),

```
  fieldOne --> is a List of StructType (similar to MyObject) 

  fieldTwo --> is a list of StructType (similar to MyObject2)
```

In order to achieve this i created my custom structtypes for MyObject, MyObject2 and my ResultType.

```scala
  val myObjSchema = StructType(List(
    StructField("name",StringType),
    StructField("age",IntegerType)
  ))

  val myObjSchema2 = StructType(List(
    StructField("xyz",StringType),
    StructField("abc",DoubleType)
  ))

  val myRecType = StructType(
    List(
      StructField("myField",ArrayType(myObjSchema)),
      StructField("myField2",ArrayType(myObjSchema2))
    )
  )
```

I populated my data within the spark `Row` object and created a dataframe

```scala
  val data = Row(
    List(MyObject("aaa",22),MyObject("sss",223)),
    List(MyObject2("bbb",23),MyObject2("abc",2332))
  )

  val df = spark.createDataFrame(
    spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(data)),myRecType
  )
```

when i call printSchema on the dataframe, the output is exactly what i would expect

```
root
 |-- myField: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- age: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- myField2: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- xyz: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- abc: double (nullable = true)
```

However when i do a show, i get a runtime exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: spark_utilities.example.MyObject is not a valid external type for schema of struct<name:string,age:int>
```

It looks like something is wrong with the Row object, can you please explain what is going wrong here?

Thanks a lot for your help!

ps: I know i can create a custom case class like `case class PH(ls:List[MyObject],ls2:List[MyObject2])` populate it and convert it to a dataset. But due to some limitations i cannot use this approach and would like to solve it in the way mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not simply insert your case class objects inside a row, you need to convert those objects to rows

```
val data = Row(
      List(Row("aaa",22.toInt),Row("sss",223.toInt)),
      List(Row("bbb",23d),Row("abc",2332d))
    ) 
val df = spark.createDataFrame(
      spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(data)),myRecType
)
```